# Vue.js Принудительное обновление

Tags: vue.js

Помогите разобраться с вопросом во Vue.js

Столкнулся со случаем использования принудительного обновления. В документации прямым текстом написано, что: *"Если вам необходимо принудительное обновление во Vue, в 99.99% случаев вы где-то совершили ошибку."*

**Сам код тут:** https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-rc1lb

**Суть вопроса:**

Есть блок с двумя инпутами, который итерируется при нажатии на кнопку "Duplicate", вызывая соответствующий метод.

Также есть кнопка "Reverse Text" - вызывает метод, который берет значение из первого инпута и переворачивает текст.

Все почти что работает, но проблема в том, что требуется вызов принудительного обновления компонента **this.$forceUpdate()** месте с вызовом метода reverseText, в противном случае не срабатывает двусторонняя связь с инпутом.

Собственно вопрос, в чем моя ошибка и как ее исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доступ по индексу массива не дает обновления. Но это легко избежать передав сам элемент массива.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-1vlrg

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, index) 
    in formData" :key="index" class="form">
      <label>
        Text:
        <input type="text" v-model="item.text">
      </label>

      <label>
        Reversed Text:
        <input type="text" v-model="item.reversedText">
      </label>
      <button @click="reverseText(item)">Reverse Text</button>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <button @click="duplicate(formData.length - 1)">Duplicate</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      formData: [
        {
          text: "",
          reversedText: ""
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    reverseText(item) {
      if (item.text) {
        item.reversedText = item.text
          .split("")
          .reverse()
          .join("");

        //this.$forceUpdate(); //--> Без этого не работает
      }
    },
    duplicate(index) {
      this.formData.push({
        text: "",
        reversedText: ""
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Тоже самое проделать с duplicate(), если предпоследний объект важен. Передайте его содержимое.

Comment: Так лучше, конечно, но по индексу реактивность сохраняется. Проблема была в том, что в массив сначала пушился пустой объект, и только потом в нем появлялись свойства. Элемент DOM рендерился на пустом объекте, поэтому реактивности не будет, т.к. нужных свойств на этот момент небыло

Comment: по индексу нет реактивности при присваивании

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-t3exp исправил только duplicate

Comment: `this.formData[index] = ...` не реактивно я имел ввиду. Кстати-и-и. Это может и плюс! Есть один моментик где мне надо убить реактивность из-за производительности частых обновлений.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Ошибка в невнимательности.</s>

В исходном массиве у вас `{text: "", reversedText: ""}`, а в `duplicate` добавляется `{name: "", reversedName: ""}`

А реактивность страдает из-за того, что сначала в массив добавляется пустой объект, а свойства в нем появляются уже после создания элементов. Для сохранения реактивности, все реактивные свойства должны присутствовать на момент рендера элементов, которые их используют.

Comment: да это не так важно, при инпуте элемент с текстом пересоздастся. хотя конструкция с копированием объекта стремная.

Comment: так понятней, но ошибка не в невнимательности,)